# Retrieve properties file from specific location

Tags: java, properties, classpath

How can I load properties file located under `src/main/resources/utility` from classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
try {
    // load a properties file
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/utility/config.properties"));

    // get the property value and print it out
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("database"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbuser"));
    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("dbpassword"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Example retrieved from http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to reference the `src/` folder but at compile time, never at runtime. Rather use `utility/config.properties`, as this matches the runtime classpath.

Comment: Infact #luanjot, you mislead the section, was section 3 with properties file from classpath, more correct way is`prop.load(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties")));`, however thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

getResourceAsStream will locate the files relative to the "root" of the classpath

initFile - File Location:

init file can also be packed as a part of war.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream uin = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(initFile);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(uin);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uin));
props.load(uin);
```